# Can you prove this equality?

Tags: optimization

In their book An Introduction to Optimization, on the chapter on gradient algorithms, to prepare for discussing convergence properties of the descent methods, authors Chong and Zak have following:

> $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx$, where $Q$ is symmetric and $Q>0$.
>
> ...
>
> $V(x)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^*=\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^T Q (x-x^*)$, where $x^*$ is the solution point obtained by solving $Qx=b$, that is, $x^*=Q^{-1}b$

I could not follow the equation $f(x)+\frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^*=\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^T Q (x-x^*)$.  Can you prove it?

Comment: can you simplify $f(x)+\frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^*$?

Comment: @LinAlg: What do you mean by simplifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
V(x)=&f(x)+\frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^* \\
=&\frac12 x^TQx-b^Tx+ \frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^* \\
=&\frac12 x^TQx-(Qx^*)^Tx+ \frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^* \\
=&\frac12 x^TQx-(x^*)^TQx+ \frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^* \quad(\because Q^T=Q)\\
=&\frac12 x^TQx-\frac12(x^*)^TQx-\frac12(x^*)^TQx+ \frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^*\\
=&\frac12 x^TQx-\frac12x^TQx^*-\frac12(x^*)^TQx+ \frac{1}{2}(x^*)^TQx^* \quad(\because Q^T=Q)\\
=& \frac{1}{2}x^T Q (x-x^*) - \frac{1}{2}(x^*)^T Q (x-x^*) \\
=&\frac{1}{2}(x-x^*)^T Q (x-x^*)
\end{align}